# Hypergeometric distribution Expectation and exchangability of variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

The expected value for hypergeometric distribution is calculated using linearity property of expectation. Th expectation is $n r_1/r$ for $n$ trials $r_1$ type 1(say red) balls out of total r balls. Here it is said that expectation of getting a red ball at $k_{th}, k<r$ position is $r_1/r$. I find that the usual explanation given for this is 
exchangeability of indicator variables. However I do not understand how this is applicable for this distribution. for Binomial distribution I can understand it as the urn from which the ball is drawn remains the same due to replacement so all indicator variables have same probability. But for this distribution I dont unerstand why. I have worked out for upto 3 variables but I am not able to generalize.

Comment: Imagine the balls have ID numbers. All orders of drawing are equally likely. Let  $r\ge 17$. The probability a particular ball appears on the $17$-th draw is the same as the probability it appears on the first draw.

Comment: @Andre Nicolas : Thank you for the answer.

Comment: You are welcome. The equally likely stuff can also be verified by conditional probability calculations, but that is very much the hard way to do it.